# Search for a set of letters in a given string - Python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to check if the `emblem` is contained in the `userString`. For `emblem` to be contained in `userString`, the characters in `emblem` should appear in `userString`.

Python code is as follows:

```
emblem = "mammoth"
userEntered = "zmzmzmzaztzozh"

print(emblem)
print(userEntered)

found = emblem in userEntered

print(found)
```

In the above case, the word `mammoth` does appear in `zmzmzmzaztzozh` (the characters `m`, `a`, `o`, `t`, `h` are all in `zmzmzmzaztzozh`), but still I get found = false. Is there a way to check if a given word appears in a scrambled string without using regular expressions in Python?

Comment: This isn't valid python syntax. What does being scrambled have to do with the result? Did the `in` operator not work for you?

Comment: `emblem in userEntered` and BTW your code snipped it not Python.

Comment: Okay.. Python code is provided and 'in' does not work for me

Comment: @ekartik What do you mean by "scrambled"? Can you show how mammoth appears in that string? Are you just talking about the presence of the letters that make up "mammoth" in that string? Letter counts?

Comment: Yes.. I'm talking about the presence of the letters that make up 'mammoth' in the given string

Comment: @ekartik Yes but is it the specific letter counts that matter? Would `"maoth"` be considered to have `"mammoth"` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
... 
... 
... def solution(emblem, user_entered):
...     return not (Counter(emblem) - Counter(user_entered))
... 
>>> solution('mammoth', 'zmzmzmzaztzozh')
True
>>> solution('mammoth', 'zmzmzmzaztzoz')
False
```

Comment: @ekartik Please consider [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), if it solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Python provides us a inbuilt function find() which checks if a substring is present in the string, which is done in one line.

```
emblem = "Mammoth"

userEntered = "zmzmzmzoztzozh"

if userEntered.find(emblem) == -1:
    print("Not Found")
else:
    print("Found")
```

find() function returns -1 if it is not found, else it returns first occurrence, so using this function this problem can be solved.

Comment: this doesn't work. To be specific, the userEntered string needs to be checked if it contains the characters 'm', 'a', 'm', 'm', 'o', 't', 'h', combined which is equal to the emblem